# Google Cloud Functions: CI/CD for Python 3.7 Runtime

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

At the end of the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/testing#continuous-testing-and-deployment) on testing your cloud function  there is a section on CI/CD. However, the only example they give is for node.  I've been trying to do something with python 3.7 to no avail.

I set up a trigger for each time I push to a Google Source Cloud repository. Its a multifunction project

```
├── actions
│   ├── action.json
│   └── main.py
├── cloudbuild.yaml
├── Dockerfile
├── graph
│   ├── main.py
│   └── requirements.txt
└── testing
    ├── test_actions.py
    └── test_graph.py
```

I've tried the [example](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/create-custom-build-steps) to make a custom build.

here is my `cloudbuild.yml`:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/momentum-360/pytest'
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.7
COPY . /
WORKDIR /
RUN pip install -r graph/requirements.txt
RUN pip install pytest
ENTRYPOINT ["pytest"]
```

I'm getting the following error when I run it in the cloud build environment (not locally):

```
"Missing or insufficient permissions.","grpc_status":7}"
E >

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
testing/test_graph.py:7: in <module>
from graph import main
```

which means I don't have enough permission to read my own files? I'm not sure I'm doing this right at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is with your `cloudbuild.yaml`. You need to configure it to build the image from the Dockerfile. [Check the official Google Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/create-basic-configuration) to know how to create a build configuration file.

I have been trying with this simple setup and it worked for me:

```
├── project
    ├── cloudbuild.yaml
    └── Dockerfile
    └── test_sample.py
```

The content of `test_sample.py`:

```
def inc(x):
   return x + 1

def test_answer():
   assert inc(3) == 4
```

Here is the `cloudbuild.yaml`:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/pytest-image', '.' ]
images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/pytest-image'
```

The `Dockerfile`, it is important to copy the project in its own directory to run pytest.

```
FROM python:3.7
COPY . /project
WORKDIR /project
RUN pip install pytest
ENTRYPOINT ["pytest"]
```

Now, inside the project directory we build the image:

`gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml .`

We pull it:

`docker pull gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/pytest-image:latest`

And run it:

`docker run gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/pytest-image:latest`

Result:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.2, pytest-4.2.0, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.1
rootdir: /src, inifile:
collected 1 item

test_sample.py .                                                         [100%]

=========================== 1 passed in 0.03 seconds ===========================
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot I'm having a bit of trouble on the run step

```
 args: [ 'run', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/pytest-image' ]
```

But I'm sure I'll figure it out.